# Remove button align justify CKeditor

Tags: javascript, php, ckeditor

I want remove align justify but give align left, right and center. I use CKeditor 4.3

Comment: What have you tried? We usually don't compose others code, but help with it.

Comment: config.js, config.toolbar = define what ever you want. there are several other approaches but i like this one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
config.removeButtons = 'JustifyBlock';
```

See [how to set a configuration](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_configuration).